# Removing an alternate username from a YouTube Channel

Tags: youtube, google-account

One of my family members made the mistake of setting their Gmail account to my YouTube Channel. I have finally gotten rid of the email as the primary but now I can't seem to figure out how to delete the alternate username. Does anyone know how to delete it or is it just there forever?